# How to add the executable file for "rails" to the $PATH of my container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nuxt.js

### Context: Setting up a Rails and nuxt project

I was following step by step this [article](https://medium.com/@fishpercolator/how-to-separate-frontend-backend-with-rails-api-nuxt-js-and-devise-jwt-cf7dd9da9d16) to no avail. I also cloned directly from author's [repo](https://github.com/fishpercolator/autheg/issues/4) and not only did I had the same issue but I am also not the onlyone

### Problem

at runtime the container does not have access to the `rails` command

**docker-compose run backend /bin/bash**

```
rails --version
#> bash: rails: command not found
```

### My files

**/backend/Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6

ARG UID
RUN adduser rails --uid $UID --disabled-password --gecos ""

ENV APP /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir $APP
WORKDIR $APP

COPY Gemfile* $APP/
RUN bundle install -j3 --path vendor/bundle

COPY . $APP/

CMD ["rails", "server", "-p", "8080", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**/frontend/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.15.0

ARG UID
RUN adduser frontend --uid $UID --disabled-password --gecos ""

ENV APP /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir $APP
WORKDIR $APP

COPY package.json yarn.lock $APP/
RUN yarn

COPY . $APP/

CMD ["yarn", "run", "dev"]
```

**/build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose build
docker-compose run -u root backend bundle
docker-compose run -u root frontend yarn
docker-compose run backend rails db:create
docker-compose up
```

### Output

**./build.sh**

```
Creating autheg_backend_run ... done
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "rails": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: 1
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
autheg_frontend_1 is up-to-date
Starting autheg_db_1 ... done
Recreating 3399533abf78_autheg_backend_1 ... error

ERROR: for 3399533abf78_autheg_backend_1  Cannot start service backend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "rails": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for backend  Cannot start service backend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "rails": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

#### What am I missing here?. How do I set properly the Dockerfiles and the docker-compose file?

Comment: Does `bundle exec rails ...` work?  There's a "better" way to express that in the Dockerfile, if so.

Comment: When I run `docker-compose up` I can see the gems being installed, but when if enter the container `docker-compose run backend /bin/bash`  and I run `bundle exec rails`  I get a "The most common rails comands are: .." message  Morover if run ` exec bundle install` from the container I do get the rails installed aftewards. But I don't know how/where to express `exec bundle install` on the docker files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby applications generally use a tool called [Bundler](https://bundler.io) to manage their application's dependencies.  If your application depends on the `rails` gem, which provides a `rails` executable, that will often be in `vendor/bin/rails` or somewhere similar, but not on the standard `$PATH`.

The quickest way to make this work is to use the [`bundle exec`](https://bundler.io/v2.2/man/bundle-exec.1.html) wrapper, which knows how to set up paths accordingly.

```sh
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", ...]
```

However, you can imagine that *every* command you want to run in this container needs that alternate-path setup.  If you're using the `rake` task runner, for example, you'd need to `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to launch migrations.  So a better path is to use the Docker `ENTRYPOINT` to provide the `bundle exec` wrapper, and leave your `CMD` as is.  If you have both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, then [the `CMD` gets passed as additional arguments to `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) and you get a single combined command, which is what you want here.

```sh
# (ENTRYPOINT must be JSON-array form for this pattern)
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
CMD ["rails", "server", "..."]
```

If you `docker run` or `docker-compose` run an alternate command, that replaces the `CMD` part, so the `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper stays intact.

```sh
# Still runs under the ENTRYPOINT from the image:
#   bundle exec rake db:migrate
docker run --rm my-image rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Very interesting. with that correction it does brings up the two endpoints. I need to do a lot fo reading to understand the intricacies of it. Thanks a lot for the links and fine directions